# Question about nerves and their roots

Tags: health-education, anatomy, nerves, neuroscience

I am new to anatomy and medical sciences in general.

The other day, I was studying the stages of the brachial plexus (the roots, divisions, trunks, cords, branches, terminations and so forth). Then I came across the axillary nerve, which I came across it before upon studying the muscles of the upper limb and their innervations. I realised this weird thing, it said that "The axillary nerve arises from the posterior cord of the brachial plexus ***(C5 and C6)*** in the axilla..." meanwhile the description for the axillary nerve in the brachial plexus section was that it originates from the posterior  cord of the brachial plexus.

I don't understand how the root of the axillary nerve is C5 and C6 despite the fact that it originates from the posterior cord of the brachial plexus which should supposedly have roots of C5,6,7,8 and T1?

Edit: The book I am studying from is Gray's Anatomy For Student's Fourth International Edition

Comment: The roots C5 - Th1 cluster in the posterior chord, and then branch off into the different nerves. The axillary nerve is supplied by only the nerves from roots C5 and C6, which temporarily associated themselves with the C7-Th1 roots.